# Right align xml data while generating PDF using fo:list-block

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo, bi-publisher

I have number list in my XML input And I am able to align list body(text content) to align right, but numbers remain aligned to left. How can I align entire list including numbers/bullets to right, by default is comes to left.
Any help or pointers is highly appreciated, Thanks.

Current output:

```html
 Number list below
 1.                                                                 L List 1
 2.                                                                 R list 2
```

My expected output :

```html
 Number list below
                                                                   1. L List 1
                                                                   2. R list 2
```

I have simplified xml data as below :

```html
<p>Number list below</p>
      <ol>
         <li style="text-align: right;">L list 1</li>
         <li style="text-align: right;">R list 2</li>
      </ol>
```

My xslt code look like below:

```html
<xsl:template match="LI|li">
 <fo:list-block> 
  <xsl:attribute name="text-align">
   <!--xsl:value-of select="end"/-->
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">right</xsl:text>
  </xsl:attribute>  
  <fo:list-item>
   <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
    <fo:block>
     <xsl:variable name="value-fetcher">
      <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="../@start">
        <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI)+ ../@start"/>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI) + 1"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
     </xsl:variable>
     <xsl:number value="$value-fetcher" format="1."/>     
    </fo:block>
   </fo:list-item-label>
   <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">   
    <fo:block>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
    </fo:block>
   </fo:list-item-body>    
  </fo:list-item>
 </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies, are always useful.

alignment achieved by below xslt:

```html
<xsl:template match="LI|li">
<fo:block margin-left="36pt" text-align="right">
 <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="-18pt"/>
 <fo:inline><xsl:variable name="value-fetcher">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="../@start">
                                <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI)+ ../@start"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI) + 1"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:number value="$value-fetcher" format="1."/> 
 </fo:inline>
 <fo:inline>
 <fo:leader leader-pattern="space" leader-length="18pt"/>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
 </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that a right-aligned, variable-width list isn't quite what `fo:list-block` was designed to do.

Assuming that your FO formatter implements `fo:table-and-caption`, you could make a table that looks like what you want:

```
  <table-and-caption text-align="right">
    <table text-align="left">
      <table-body>
        <table-row>
          <table-cell padding="1pt">
            <block>1.</block>
          </table-cell>
          <table-cell padding="1pt">
            <block>L List 1</block>
          </table-cell>
        </table-row>
      </table-body>
      <table-body>
        <table-row>
          <table-cell padding="1pt">
            <block>2.</block>
          </table-cell>
          <table-cell padding="1pt">
            <block>R list 2</block>
          </table-cell>
        </table-row>
      </table-body>
    </table>
  </table-and-caption>
```

---

In the absence of `fo:table-and-caption`, you can abuse `fo:block-container` and the `writing-mode` property:

```
  <block-container writing-mode="rl">
    <table text-align="left" writing-mode="lr">
```

or you can use `fo:leader` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_leader) to 'push' an `fo:inline-container` (https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_inline-container) to the right:

```
  <block>
    <leader leader-length.optimum="100%"/><inline-container>
    <table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
"fo:table-and-caption" is not yet supported, Is there any other way to achieve this formatting.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your template:

- you are not setting [`provisional-distance-between-starts`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#provisional-distance-between-starts) which, together with [`provisional-label-separation`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#provisional-label-separation) determines the width of the item label, so you get a width of 24pt - 6pt = 18pt
- your item labels don't have the required `end-indent="label-end()"`, and the item bodies are missing `start-indent="body-start()"`, so they are not properly sized / positioned.

This revised template should work:

```
<xsl:template match="LI|li">
    <fo:list-block text-align="end" provisional-distance-between-starts="3cm"><!-- set the value you want! -->  
        <fo:list-item>
            <fo:list-item-label end-indent="label-end()">
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:variable name="value-fetcher">
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="../@start">
                                <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI)+ ../@start"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI) + 1"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:number value="$value-fetcher" format="1."/>                    
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-label>
            <fo:list-item-body start-indent="body-start()">         
                <fo:block>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
                </fo:block>
            </fo:list-item-body>                
        </fo:list-item>
    </fo:list-block>
</xsl:template>
```

Just a minor nitpick: you are creating an `fo:list-block` for each `li` element in your input, while you could create just one for each `ol` or `ul`.

---

As you don't know in advance the width to reserve for the label, but it depends on the item text itself ... well, maybe you don't need to use an `fo:list-block` at all!

A right-aligned `fo:block` should be enough, provided the item text always creates just one line:

```
<xsl:template match="LI|li">
    <fo:block text-align="end"> 
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:variable name="value-fetcher">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="../@start">
                        <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI)+ ../@start"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:number value="count(preceding-sibling::li) + count(preceding-sibling::LI) + 1"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:number value="$value-fetcher" format="1."/>                    
        </fo:inline> 
        <fo:inline>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="text()"/>
        </fo:inline>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
I am able to get expected output for sample input by setting provisional-distance-between-starts="14cm", 
But that's not the case always with increase in list string size it overlaps .
Is it possible to calculate "provisional-distance-between-starts" dynamically based on string size or page width.

Comment: Basically my string size going to change  based on user entered text.  Thanks.

Comment: Answer updated: if the user entered text is just one line, this is even simpler!